# POST https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://embedded-game.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-10/draft_orders.json 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: api, cors, shopify

```
const url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://embedded-game.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-10/draft_orders.json'

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'SHOPIFY_API_KEY': '___',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "draft_order": {
        "line_items": [
          {
            "custom": false,
            "title": "Custom Product",
            "product_id": 4008421883976,
            "price": "1000.00",
            "properties": [
              {
                "name": "custom engraving",
                "value": "Happy Birthday Mom!"
              }
            ],
            "quantity": 5
          }
        ],
        "customer": {
          "id": 1000
        },
        "email": "abhisheksrivastavabbn@gmail.com"
      }
    })
  };

  const createOrder = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Order Create Button clicked")
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then(
        console.log("Order Created!!")
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

I am creating a draft order in Shopify, but the response I am getting is 401, i.e, unauthenticated.
Although I have passed API key, I don't know why it's showing unauthenticated.

Initially, I was facing **CORS issue** to I added `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` before my URL. Now CORS issue is resolved, but how to deal with 401 error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your header name is wrong. Instead of `SHOPIFY_API_KEY`, the Shopify [documentation](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-a-private-app-with-shopify-admin#generate-credentials-from-the-shopify-admin) says it should be named `X-Shopify-Access-Token`.

Also, **NEVER** pass authentication information through an untrusted proxy like you are doing for CORS. If you need to add CORS headers, set up your own instance of that (or another) proxy.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make sure never to pass authentication information through an untrusted proxy. And here I have used `X-Shopify-Access-Token` instead of `SHOPIFY_API_KEY` but still, it's giving a 401 error.